Get Azure AD Access token for a different App
I have a .NET Blazor SPA application where users are being authenticated with Azure AD using MicrosoftIdentityWebApp nuget. Got some new requirements to call a 3rd party API and they are expecting an Azure Access Token. Looking over some documentation it seems that OnBehalfOf flow is what I need ( please correct me if I am wrong ). I have updated my authentication configuration and added this response type OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdTokenToken and also added a couple of OpenIdConnectEvents in order to grab the Access Token during authentication.
Just want to confirm if in order to authenticate for another application, is there a more appropriate way then OBO flow?

We don't need on-behalf-flow here. Referring to the document for this flow we could see that it require an access token for another scope as one of the parameter to generate a new access token for another scope. In other words, this flow is used for calling one API1(require an access token) and this API requires to call another API2(require an access token too), API1 and API2 both requires the same authentication. SPA can do the authentication but the API1 can't, so that API1 use this flow to generate access token for API2.
In your scenario, it's SPA to call API2 directly, maybe there isn't an API1 indeed, so that we don't need to use this flow. Here's a sample for Blazor WASM app to integrate Azure AD and generate access token to call external API. We can create a new blazor WASM app for testing purpose, remember to choose Microsoft identity plaform as the Authentication type. Then you need to modify the appsettings.json file so that you could use Microsoft account to sign into your application.

The rest is configuring the app to generate access token used for calling external API. Then in the page component, using codes below to generate access token. I referred to this document. My scope used below is the API permission I set in Azure AD, in your scenario, you need to ask the API developing team which scope you need to use.
@inject IAccessTokenProvider TokenProvider

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var result = await TokenProvider.RequestAccessToken(new AccessTokenRequestOptions
        {
            Scopes = new[] { "api://client_id_exposing_api/Tiny.Read" }
        });
    if (result.TryGetToken(out var token))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {token.Value}");
        var res = token.Value;
    }
}

Here's my test result and just like you can see the token contains the scope I set.

